# Specifying content type when using downloadr to download PDFs with R

Tags: r, pdf, download

I wrote a script to download all of the Human Rights Reports from the State Departments website. The problem is that I don't the code for which PDFs are Human Rights Reports, which are other reports and what codes don't correspond to any PDFs at all. I have figured out how to identify the non-PDFs by looking at the size of the file downloaded and I can use the package pdftools to see which of the real PDFs are Human Rights Reports and change them accordingly.

But I am wondering if I can somehow specify to only download PDFs at the initial download? When I run the this code:

```
### pdf codes on state department
pdf_code <- seq(277000, 277999, 1) 

### download 2017

for (i in seq_along(pdf_code)){
download(paste0("https://www.state.gov/documents/organization/", 
pdf_code[i], ".pdf"),
paste0(pdf_code[i], ".pdf"), mode = "wb")}
```

I can see in the console that it is parsing the content type of the download, for instance:

```
trying URL 'https://www.state.gov/documents/organization/265992.pdf'
Content type 'text/html' length 25403 bytes (24 KB)
downloaded 24 KB

trying URL 'https://www.state.gov/documents/organization/265993.pdf'
Content type 'application/pdf' length 78527 bytes (76 KB)
downloaded 76 KB
```

Is there anyway I can specify so it only downloads files that are Content type 'application/pdf'?